# How do I change selected option based on different element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to change the selected option of a select, based on clicking a fully different item, but the change is not actually working.

I have the following jQuery function

```
        $(".fake-label").click(function () {
            console.log(attribute[1]);
            $("#media_professions_select").val(attribute[1]).trigger('change');
        });
```

And the following HTML, but nothing happens. Attribute[1] is "Freelance Journalist"

```
                <select required id="media_professions_select">
                    <option disabled selected>Make a Choice</option>
                    <option value="Freelance Journalist">Freelance Journalist</option>
                </select>
```

I tried, .val(), with .trigger() and without. Also .attr("selected", true) does not do the trick.

Comment: Is your media_select also a [tag:select2]?   You do have the `.trigger("change")` so shouldn't matter, but would not update without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val(value)` should absolutely work if it's an exact match (spaces, case etc)

```js
$(".fake-label").click(function() {
  let a = "Freelance Journalist"
  $("#media_professions_select").val(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='fake-label'>click</button>

<select required id="media_professions_select">
  <option disabled selected>Make a Choice</option>
  <option value="Freelance Journalist">Freelance Journalist</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thought so too, which confuses me..

Comment: Changed it to;
`let a = "Freelance Journalist"
$('#media_professions_select').val(a);`
Still no luck...

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are you sure you have that option with the exact value you're looking for?

Comment: @S_NoBEl the snippet provided for you here shows that `.val(value)` works fine, *given the information you have provided*.  If it's still not working for you, then there must be some other issue or some other info you're not telling us.   Please copy the snippet to your question and update it so that it *demonstrates the issue*.

Comment: Figured it out. The select was hidden through CSS (and I did not consider to make it visible). I kept checking the selected state through the inspector, but apparently it does not update there. Upon making it visible I did see the selected value actually changing..